# What portions of the Delimbiyr River are navigable by ship?

Tags: forgotten-realms

Some images of the Sword Coast show the Lizard Marshes south of the mouth of the Delimbiyr, and others show it ending at the Lizard Marshes.

[image: Navigable?]

[image]

The description from Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting 2nd edition (revised) and Storm King's Thunder says

> Eventually, the river dissolved into a morass of waterways, forming a vast swamp known as the Lizard Marsh.

Further, according to Scourge of the Sword Coast,

> The waterways of the Delimbiyr at Daggerford were too shallow for ships to **continue upriver** into the rest of the Delimbiyr Vale.

*emphasis mine*

This seemingly contradicts Storm King's Thunder

> In this stretch, the Delimbiyr was especially wide, giving the settlement enough room for a modest harbor.

Unless that's meant to imply the Delimbiyr is navigable northeast of Loudwater. But then why would ships be at Daggerford in the first place, if the mouth is not traversable and neither is anything south of Loudwater?

Maybe it's navigable from the Sword Sea to Daggerford, and then from Loudwater northeast, but not between Daggerford and Loudwater?

Comment: Is there any word about what uses this modest harbour? Fishing boats can use one, too, but are not ships. Then, there are ships and ships.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the contradiction.  Why are you assuming the mouth / swamp / marsh is not navigable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Boats can navigate the river upstream of Daggerford

A ship typically is a larger vessel, its [dictionary defintion](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20ship) is:

> a large boat for transporting people or goods by sea

So the statements you cite are not contradictory. That the river is *too shallow* for ships, and that it is *espcially wide* is consistent -- the same volume of water needs to flow through, and typically the wider the river is at some point, the shallower it is. Smaller vessels like boats and barges that do not need as much depth could still navigate and use the river upsteam of Daggerford.

There is a slight disconnect betweent the the maps and published text for the Lizard Marsh. The maps, especially the larger-scale one, make it look as if there could be a navigable channel for ships through the Marsh. However *Ghosts of Dragonspear Castle* was published by Wizards for D&D Next and says (p. 12):

> Instead of flowing freely into the Sea of Swords, the Delimbiyr River (also called the Shining River) dissolves into a morass of waterways threading around and beneath trees festooned with moss, forming a vast swamp.

This seems to indicate, there is no way to steer a ship through the Lizard Marsh to Daggerford, or from there to the sea.

I am not sure from where you got the quote you have for *Scourge of the Sword Coast* about "*ships to continue upriver*". (I think you got that from the [Forgotten Realms wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Daggerford), which uses that text and cites the module as its source). However, while the wiki is generally very good, I cannot find the text you cite anywhere in the module. That module merely states (p. 12)

> The Delimbiyr River becomes shallow at Daggerford (hence the "ford" in its name), so boat traffic from the east has to stop. This traffic meets with caravns traveling north and south on the Trade Way.

This would fit with a setup where you have boat traffic up and down the Delimbiyr River, but no ship traffic from Daggerford out to the sea, or from the sea via Daggerford and further up the river.

Comment: I see. The disconnect is boats have to stop after coming downstream, like from Loudwater, not that they have to stop from coming inland from the shore. Thanks for clearing that up!